# IP/TCP - most common use cases

Tags: tcp, ip, osi

What are the most common use cases for IP and TCP?

I  am trying to find out what might be the best use cases for IP and TCP connections but unfortunately I wasn't very succesful so far.

Comment: Take a look at what's used on the Internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is used for reliable connections, when packets mustn't be dropped. It's slower than UDP, because sender must have 100% certainty, that the data has been delivered without errors. IP is unreliable and its only a kind of a envelope, where is recipent and sender specified and some other data.

Read more about tcp/ip model for example on wikipedia. Try to find on your own before asking.

Comment: I asked about use cases, I knew that Information already. What I meant was ; In which protocols is TCP  and IP being used mostly

Comment: Tcp is used for example in delivering emails, downloading files, searching the internet (HTTP). And IP is a main Network layer protocol  used in the internet all over the world. It is used, when you need to transfer some data between points in the network. IP is used in the internet for routing packets in the internet. It is prepared to be very fast-switched, because in 60's, were slow processors, and every single bit of data was a load for switch/router.